# Sublime text command history random behavior

Tags: python, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I've recently decided to migrate to sublime text as my primary editor. Unfortunately, some of the built-in tools (including the delete line macro) did not satisfy me, so I decided to write a simple plugin for deleting the current line.

I decided to use the view.command_history method to trace the chaining of the command. Unfortunately, the API seems to have a somewhat inconsistent behavior for the method:

```
# This doesn't work
if self.view.command_history(0)[0] != 'delete_line':
    self.lastpos = coords[1]

# This does
if self.view.command_history(0)[0] != 'delete_line':
    sublime.error_message(str(self.view.command_history(0)))
    self.lastpos = coords[1]
```

[GitHub](https://github.com/v--/SublimeDeleteLine/blob/master/Delete%20Line.py)

This is my first time writing more than 15 lines in python and, at least according to pylint, I'm a total idiot. So, gurus of the internet, is my code plain stupid is the API really inconsistent?

PS: Everything works, except for the above block

Comment: Your code looks sane enough; are you saying that your `self.lastpos` assignment produces an error unless you first called `sublime.error_message()`?

Comment: No, I'm saying that it simply doesn't work - lastpos gets reassigned every time the function is ran - the only place it can ever be reassigned is inside the above block (by reassigning I mean a new value, not the default one). In other words, the code always works, but only with displaying some kind of message lastpos doesn't get reassigned when it doesn't need to be. It seems more like a bug, but there's nothing I can lose by asking on Stack Overflow.